# href in pug-php not working

Tags: php, pug

Hi does anyone know how to use href in Pug?

What I want to achieve is this:

```
<noscript class="lazyload">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css">
</noscript>
```

I tried this, but it is not working.

```
noscript.lazyload
        link(rel='stylesheet', href!="<? php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css ")
```

This is my gulpfile.babel.js config:

```
import pug from 'gulp-pug'
import rename from 'gulp-rename'
import pugPHPFilter from 'pug-php-filter'

gulp.task('pug', () => {
    let option = {
        pretty: true,
        filters: {
            php: pugPHPFilter
        }
    }
    return gulp.src('./pug/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug(option))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.php'
        }))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: I have no clue about `pug` but this makes me wonder: `href!="<? php` - first the `!`, second the space between `<?` and `php`

Answer (score 0):

I convert your html to pug usign https://html2jade.org/ and this is the result:

```
  noscript.lazyload
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css')
```

Try to assign PHP into Javascript var:

```
noscript.lazyload
    -var template_uri = <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
    link(rel='stylesheet', href=template_uri+'/style.css')
```

Comment: I don't know.You could try to assign php to javascript var. I edited the post!